# Python and SQL timezones

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime

I'm using python to create a datetime value with Europe/London timezone:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone, utc

now_utc = datetime.datetime.now()
now_uk = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/London')) # convert to local time
```

I then want to add this value to a SQL database using `sqlite3` within python.

```
cursor = con.cursor()
sql_data = ("INSERT INTO TCADATA (datetime, gym1) VALUES (datetime(:datetime), :gym1;")
cursor.execute(sql_data, {"datetime":now_uk, "gym1":data["gym1"]})
```

The value that gets added to the SQL database is one hour different from my London timezone, so if it's 16:00 here, the value in the database is 15:00.

My guess is that SQLite3 is converting the datetime to UTC.

How do I specify to sqlite that the value is a London time zone? I would prefer to specify London like I have done with python, rather than GMT since this changes at daylight savings.

Or perhaps it would be simpler to keep it as UTC and convert it to London time when the data is read?

Comment: What is your local time zone? Are you using pytz?

Comment: SQLite has no datetime data type, much less one that includes a timezone, so you'll need some way to store the timezone information.  You can either serialize to a string that includes the timezone, or store it in a separate field.

Comment: Yes, I'm using pytz. The local timezone is British Summer Time (BST). It'd be GMT in the winter though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get round this issue is to either store the datetimes in UTC timezone on the server and convert to local time zones as needed when retrieving the data in python.